# Processing: saveFrame() and retina display

Tags: processing, retina-display, retina

I'm trying to export frames from a Processing sketch using the saveFrame() function, but they come out very rough, specially the fonts. I'm on a Mac with retina display and even though when I'm running the sketch everything looks good and sharp, when I save the frames they look bad.

I have included the following lines (in the setup function) but they don't improve the outcome of the saveFrame() function:

```
size(1280, 720, "processing.core.PGraphicsRetina2D");
hint(ENABLE_RETINA_PIXELS);
smooth(8);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you share some code that will reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text is clean with this sketch, do you run it in java mode ?

```
// size(960, 540); //

size(960, 540, "processing.core.PGraphicsRetina2D");
hint(ENABLE_RETINA_PIXELS);

textSize(32);
text("word", 10, 30); 
fill(0, 102, 153);
text("word", 10, 60);
fill(0, 102, 153, 51);
text("word", 10, 90);
```

If you like a clean retina screenshot, you need to double your sketch size with `size(1920,1080)`.
If you need this picture for a website you can use this html `<img src="retina" width="960" height="540">`

Comment: Thank you. Yes, you do need to double the sketch size.